# Laravel Eloquent: Best Way to Calculate Total Price

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Im building a simple buy and sell application with Laravel 5.1. Each Buy Model has many BuyDetail which stores bought item quantity and buy_price. I have implement the relationship between table on the Model.

```
class Buy extends Model
{
  #Eloquent relationships

  public function supplier()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier');
  }

  public function buyDetails()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\BuyDetail');
  }
}
```

I'd like to calculate the total price for each Buy. What is the best way to calculate the total price using Eloquent ORM?

for now i just implement it like this:

```
@foreach($buys as $key => $value)
    <?php
        $total = 0;
    ?>
    @foreach($value->buyDetails as $k => $bD)
        <?php
            $total += ($bD['buy_price']*$bD['qty']);
    ?>
    @endforeach

   <tr>
    <td>{{$value->ref_number}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->suplier->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$value->buyDetails->count()}}</td>
    <td>{{$total}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" title="show">Detail</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="edit">Edit</a>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="delete">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is the correct spelling "Supplier"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be done in (at least) 2 ways.

Using pure Eloquent model logic:

```
class Buy extends Model
{
  public function getTotalPrice() {
    return $this->buyDetails->sum(function($buyDetail) {
      return $buyDetail->quantity * $buyDetail->price;
    });
  }
}
```

The only issue here is that it needs to fetch all buy details from the database but this is something you need to fetch anyway to display details in the view.

If you wanted to avoid fetching the relation from the database you could build the query manually:

```
class Buy extends Model
{
  public function getTotalPrice() {
    return $this->buyDetails()->sum(DB::raw('quantity * price'));
  }
}
```

Comment: this is works :). Thanks. I prefer the 2nd approach, now i can just access it via $value->getTotalPrice(). 

note: too many closing branches on the 2nd code

Comment: When I try to use this second approach, it gives me the following error:

Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Any ideas why?

Comment: Hae you defined the buyDetails() method? It should return the relation definition

Comment: I have a problem in laravel please see if you can answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318866/unable-to-retrieve-data-sent-via-ajax-in-controller-laravel-5-1)

Comment: @Adamnick Please don’t summon me to answer your questions.

Comment: @Adamnick You specifically asked me to answer your question as though I were a performing monkey. I don’t appreciate that. I choose which questions I’ll answer.

Answer (score 9):

I realise an answer’s already been accepted, but just thought I’d add my own detailing another approach.

Personally, I like to put “aggregate” methods like these on custom collection classes. So if I have a `Buy` model that can have many `BuyDetail` models, then I would put a `getTotal()` method on my `BuyDetailCollection` method like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as EloquentCollection;

class BuyDetailCollection extends EloquentCollection
{
    public function getTotal()
    {
        return $this->items->sum(function ($detail) {
            return $detail->price * $detail->quantity;
        });
    }
}
```

I can then add this to the `BuyDetail` model:

```
class BuyDetail extends Model
{
    public function newCollection(array $models = [])
    {
        return new BuyDetailCollection($models);
    }
}
```

And use my `getTotal()` method where ever I need to now:

```
$buy = Buy::with('buyDetails')->find($id);

$total = $buy->buyDetails->getTotal();
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- I've thought about doing a custom collection before but didn't realize it was so easy.

Comment: Great one @Martin Bean