# Laravel Price calculation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've tried to calculate the total sum of an order with help of this: 
[Laravel Eloquent: Best Way to Calculate Total Price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421666/laravel-eloquent-best-way-to-calculate-total-price)

I want the calculation to be done in the model, so I can use it in multiple controllers.

My code looks like this:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
    }

    public function total()
    {
        return $this->orderItems->sum(function($orderItem)
            {
                return $orderItem->net_price;
            });
    }
}
```

So I think I have done everything exactly like in the example, but I'm getting following error:

> ErrorException in Model.php line 2696: Relationship method must return
>   an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: right now im not calling it at all and get the error anyway.

Comment: Before i called it from the view with {{ $order->total }} and  {{ $order->total() }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joha, I would be very careful using the sum function on a collection when you are working with decimal values. This will not be relevant if you are using integer values.

You may find that the sum function will sometimes miscalculate the sum, and leave you with quirky numbers like `59.999999999998184`. This is because decimal operations aren't very stable in computers, so you must loop around each item and use **bcmath** instead to avoid this. Even if you're not experiencing it now, as the app grows, this would become a problem.

Here would be a more secure & accurate example:

```
class Order extends Model{

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
    }

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
    }

    public function getTotalAttribute() {
        $totalPrice = 0;

        foreach ($this->orderItems as $orderItem) {
            $totalPrice = bcadd($totalPrice, $orderItem->net_price, 2);
        }

        return $totalPrice;
    }
}
```

I would also refactor the function into an attribute, as shown in the code example. This allows you to access `$order->total` as if it was an attribute on the model.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how / where is the refactorization done, so i can use it as an attribute? just by calling the function get....Attribute() ?

Comment: The refactorization is done in the code contained in my answer.

The way this works is because the name of the function is `getTotalAttribute()`. Laravel automatically picks up on this, and now in your view/controller where you have an order, you can access `$order->total` and it will return the value of the `getTotalAttribute()` function. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public function total() {
    return $this->orderItems->sum('net_price');
}
```

Comment: what about the second option in that answer. ```$this->orderItems()->sum(DB::raw('net_price'));```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you `hasMany` relationship. Try this:

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\OrderItem::class, 'order_id');
}
```

Of course, you must change `order_id` to the name that holds the information in the OrderItem's table.

Comment: wait a second i will try it. but i dont think this is the problem, because in the controller i can loop through the orderitems using foreach ($order->orderItems as orderItem) {...}

Comment: since 'order id' is the foreign key in my orderItems table this should work by default the way i had it before, right?

Comment: It should. But, since I did not see any other problem I thought we should try it.

Comment: Then look to $Vinicius Dias answer. Maybe your namespacing is wrong.

Comment: Yes. Another thing I changed was not to use a literal string. I'm getting the class fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the function is correct and the problem was that the view from where i called it was not uploaded correctly after i changed it. the call in the view must be {{ $order->total() }}

Thanks for your help guys!